# A directory must be empty before being deleted

Tags: python, pandas, database, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

please how can i "A directory must be empty before being deleted." do it in my jupyter notebooko

i dont know how to do it and this is my frst time using
it so am a novice

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code checks for contents inside a specific folder.
If no files are found in that directory, then we can delete the Folder.

```
import os
  
# path of the directory
directoryPath = "D:/My_directory/My_project/Folder_to_Test"
  
# Comparing the returned list to empty list
if os.listdir(directoryPath) == []:
        print("No files found in the directory.")
        os.rmdir(directoryPath)
    else:
        print("Some files found in the directory.")
```